# Getting Cross-thread operation not valid in SetWindowPos()

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, multithreading, exception

I am trying to access a form from a different thread to that on which the form was created, and finally ended up with an error:

> Cross thread operation not valid

Code:

```
public static void MakeTopMost(Form form)
{
    SetWindowPos(form.Handle, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, TOPMOST_FLAGS);
}
```

I am passing a form which is running in another thread.  I tried testing `InvokeRequired`, but it is always false.

I am new to threading.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cross-thread operation not valid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5037470/cross-thread-operation-not-valid)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Make sure you are testing the right object for `InvokeRequired`:

```
public static void MakeTopMost(Form form)
{
    if (form.InvokeRequired)
    {
        form.Invoke((Action)delegate { MakeTopMost(form); });
        return;
    }

    SetWindowPos(form.Handle, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, TOPMOST_FLAGS);
}
```

I like to wrap all of this up with an extension method like this:

```
public static class SynchronizeInvokeUtil
{
    public static void SafeInvoke(this ISynchroniseInvoke sync, Action action)
    {
        if (sync.InvokeRequired)
            sync.Invoke(action);
        else
            action();
    }

    public static void SafeBeginInvoke(this ISynchroniseInvoke sync, 
                                       Action action)
    {
        if (sync.InvokeRequired)
            sync.BeginInvoke(action);
        else
            action();
    }
}
```

You can then just call:

```
form.SafeInvoke(() => SetWindowPos(form.Handle, HWND_TOPMOST, 
                                   0, 0, 0, 0, TOPMOST_FLAGS));
```

Which is probably the most readable.

Note that if you are using this within the form class itself, you have to use `this.SafeInvoke(...)` in order to access the extension method.

Comment: @Drew Noakes, now there is no error in cross threading operation, but still no fruits. Its not getting my form to front.

Comment: @karthik - if you can't get the form to the front, have another search on SO (I'm sure there are lots of questions about that on here).  If that doesn't help, ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

this works to me with text control

```
  void updateValue(string value)
  {
      currentThread.Text = value;
  }


this.currentThread.Invoke(updateValue, Thread.CurrentThread.Name);
```